# rgbdslam with electric install

Tags: slam, navigation, rosmake, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used ROS fuerte and find it's too hard to make rgbdslam，so I use ROS electric now.
I follow the tutorial(http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam),and I use Ubuntu 11.10 OS.
From my first time to rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam,all package have compiled :

,but when start linking  ,there are many error to remind me cannot find ***.so file

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2o_stuff/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so
```

so,I modify rgbdslam/CMakeFile.txt ,and set libs,finally CMakeFile.txt turn into this :
(line 177)

```
SET(LIBS_LINK rgbdslam GL GLU g2o_types_slam3d g2o_solver_cholmod g2o_solver_pcg g2o_solver_csparse g2o_core cxsparse g2o_stuff QtOpenGL ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

meanwhile I download a libQtOpenGL.so file,and put it into /lib/i386-linux-gnu/
but now,Error are different:

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `LinearSolverCholmod':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:75: undefined reference to `cholmod_start'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:75: undefined reference to `cholmod_start'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::init()':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:98: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `~LinearSolverCholmod':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:89: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:92: undefined reference to `cholmod_finish'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:89: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:92: undefined reference to `cholmod_finish'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::computeSymbolicDecomposition(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:252: undefined reference to `cholmod_analyze'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:278: undefined reference to `cholmod_amd'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:301: undefined reference to `cholmod_analyze_p'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solvePattern(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > const&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:202: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:207: undefined reference to `cholmod_change_factor'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solve(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&, double*, double*)':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:123: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:130: undefined reference to `cholmod_solve'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:132: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_dense'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solveBlocks(double**&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:162: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/zhutou/ros/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:167: undefined reference to `cholmod_change_factor'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/glviewer.o: In function `GLViewer::drawToPS(QString)':
/home/zhutou/ros/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:676: undefined reference to `gl2psBeginPage'
/home/zhutou/ros/rgbdslam/src/glviewer.cpp:678: undefined reference to `gl2psEndPage'
```

what happened？What should I do now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40001/rgbdslam-with-electric-install/) by [pig's head](https://answers.ros.org/users/2932/pig%27s-head/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pig's head](https://answers.ros.org/users/2932/pig%27s-head/) on 2012-07-27**:
Hi ,@allenh1,I have  built all package include g2o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I too had some similar problem. Don't edit anything in cmakelist.txt. Try

$ rosmake --pre-clean rgbdslam.

If it is not working. Tell me what you have done to solve the dependency problem of eigen package for rgbdslam. this might also be a problem.

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0